# How are the muscles of some dead animals still able to function for an extended period of time without oxygen?

Tags: muscles

I found [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjslGKlqCdk) that features several butchered and sometimes cooked animals that are still able to move despite of this. Some of these animals have been dead for several hours already but they're still able to move, like [this frog](https://youtu.be/hjslGKlqCdk?t=5) or [this chicken filet](https://youtu.be/hjslGKlqCdk?t=21). Other animals still display movement after they've been cooked in the oven, [like this fish](https://youtu.be/hjslGKlqCdk?t=172).

These aren't just random movements either. Some of the animals still seem to be able to respond to aversive stimuli as well. An example of this is [the decapitated fish at 0:30](https://youtu.be/hjslGKlqCdk?t=30) that only starts moving when its being sliced by a knife. Another example is this [this dried fish at 1:21](https://youtu.be/hjslGKlqCdk?t=81) that starts moving its mouth when a bit of water is poured
over it.

So how are these dead animals still moving without their muscles receiving any oxygen? I've looked up how long muscles can survive without oxygen. In humans [this appears to be 60 to 90 minutes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1114253/) at most. Perhaps the same goes for many other vertibrate species. But the compilation even shows cooked animals still able to move. So how does this work?

Comment: Check out muscle metabolism.

Comment: @theforestecologist how is this an answer?

Comment: It's not. It's a comment. I think you'd benefit from reading about the different pathways/mechanisms of muscle metabolism. You might find particular interest in anaerobic glycolysis

Comment: Please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to further understand how the site works. Thanks